# How to convert HHMM into time in minutes in excel

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery, datetime-format

I have a column in excel in hhmm format. Note that there is no ':' in the middle. Also they are not zero padded. For example 620 is 6:20 AM.
1820 is 18:20 or 6:20 PM.
How do I convert this column into minutes.
My intention is to subtract two such columns to obtain the time difference in minutes.

Comment: 129 is 1:29? or 12:9 ?

Comment: 129 is 1:29 ;   
12:9 would be 1209 ;    
ie they are not zero padded for hours

Answer (score 1):

Formula:

```
=INT(A1/100)*60+MOD(A1,100)
```

converts your timevalue into minutes

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can perform some transformation in **Power Query Editor** for your purpose as stated below-

Let your data looks like below-

[image]

Here is **Advanced Editor** code for new steps-

```
let
    //Your existing code,

    #"Split Column by Position" = Table.SplitColumn(#"previous_step_name", "time_in_number", Splitter.SplitTextByPositions({0, 2}, true), {"time_in_number.1", "time_in_number.2"}),
    #"Merged Columns" = Table.CombineColumns(#"Split Column by Position",{"time_in_number.1", "time_in_number.2"},Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(":", QuoteStyle.None),"Merged"),
    #"Changed Type2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Merged Columns",{{"Merged", type time}})
in
    #"Changed Type2"
```

Here is the final output-

[image]